# Let $f_n: \Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the supremum norm $||.||$. Check the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $f_n: \Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ is a
> Cauchy sequence in the supremum norm $||.||$. Check the uniform
> convergence of $( f_n)$

$$(f_n)  \text{ Cauchy in } (C, || .||) \\
\rightarrow  \forall  \epsilon > 0\;\; \exists N_0 \in\mathbb{N} \; \ni |f_n(z) -f_m(z)| < \epsilon \;\;\forall n,m \geq N_0 \text{ and } \forall\; z\in \Omega  \;\;\ldots(1) \\
 \rightarrow \forall  \epsilon > 0\;\; \text{ and fixed } z\in \Omega\;\; \exists N_0 \in\mathbb{N} \; \ni |f_n(z) -f_m(z)| < \epsilon \;\;\forall n,m \geq N_0  \\
\rightarrow  (f_n(z)) \text{ is Cauchy 
in } (\mathbb{C}, |.|) \; \forall z\in \Omega  \\
 (\mathbb{C}, |.|)\text{ is complete and so converges pointwise to say } f(z) \; \forall z\in \Omega \\ \text{This means that } \forall z\in\Omega \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(z) = f(z) \\
\text{Letting } m\to \infty \text{ in } (1) \text{ we get }  \\
\rightarrow  \forall  \epsilon > 0\;\; \exists N_0 \in\mathbb{N} \; \ni |f_n(z) -f(z)| < \epsilon \;\;\forall n\geq N_0 \text{ and } \forall\; z\in \Omega  \\ \rightarrow || f_n - f|| \to 0 \\
\rightarrow (f_n) \text{ converges uniformly to } f$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: I think it would be worth improving the formatting for ease of reading.  Use more words and more familiar "paragraph style" to make the steps clear.  Just throwing notation around seems to have invited a few typos to creep into the presentation.

Comment: You say that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{C}$, but that slightly is inaccurate. What you should say is that for any fixed $z \in \mathbb{C}$, the sequence of complex numbers $(f_n(z))$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{C}$. And then you define your candidate limit function as $f(z) := \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(z)$ (which exists since $\mathbb{C}$ is complete) and show that your sequence $(f_n)$ converges to this $f$ in the supremum norm.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts I wrote that it converges pointwise to $f$ because it is Cauchy in $|.|$. I have explained more now, can you check. Also, I will incorporate the correction made by José Carlos Santos

Comment: It is a very minor point but it is technically wrong to say that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{C}$ because $(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions which do not live in $\mathbb{C}$. What is true is that for any fixed complex number $z$, the sequence $(f_n(z))$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts I corrected again. Actually I am doing analysis after a long time and that is why am not being particular about things. But your corrections are definitely helping me a lot here.

Comment: It looks a lot better. Nice job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem when you say the, letting $m\to\infty$, you get $|f_n(z)-f(z)|<\varepsilon$. All you can deduce is that $|f_n(z)-f(z)|\leqslant\varepsilon$. So, take a number $\varepsilon'\in(0,\varepsilon)$. Using your argument you get that $|f_n(z)-f(z)|\leqslant\varepsilon$ and that therefore $\|f_n-f\|\leqslant\varepsilon'<\varepsilon$.

Otherwise, it looks fine.